# How to open files and applications on Python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, sys

I have some Python code and I want to open some files, applications and folders. I tried to do this with sys and os -

```
sys.open('C:\\Users\\___\\!FILMS!')
os.open('C:\\Users\\___\\!FILMS!')
```

but it isn't working. Help, please

Answer (score 0):

read and write (here copy inputfile.txt -> outputfile.txt):

```
import os

with open("inputfile.txt", "r") as fin, open("outputfile.txt", "w") as fout:
    data = fin.read()
    # do something...
    fout.write(data)
```

Comment: It says `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Comment: You need to check your file permissions...do you hv read permission?